# Could not build module 'UIKit" in cocoapods since Xcode 5.1

Tags: uikit, cocoapods, xcode5.1

I cannot build my application anymore since I updated Xcode to the new version (Xcode 5.1).
the error message is 'Could not build module 'UIKit''. 
I have the same problems with my two pods:
AFNetworking
SDWebImage

Any thought on this?

Comment: Updating to xocde 5.1.1 and clean+build solved my issue.

Comment: Please put the solution you've found into an answer below, rather than into the question. [It's perfectly acceptable to answer your own question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120215/ended-up-solving-my-own-problem-question-what-to-do-with-the-post?lq=1).

Comment: Just a tip: This occurred when I accidentally typed something in `UICollectionView.h`, replacing it physically inside sdk folder with another fresh copy of this header from my friend's sdk solved this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I solved the issue by deleting and adding UIKit.framework in Build Phases -> Link Binary With Libraries.

Answer (score 21):

I met the similar problem. The only difference is that my error is "Could not build module SpriteKit".

I finally solved the problem by deleting all files inside the ModuleCache folder: /Users/YOUR_USER_NAME/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache
Then I build and met errors to prompt me to clean build. I clean the project and rebuild and everything is fine.

I think the cause is that I once played Xcode 6, and it has new modules which missing some architectures (in my case, it is armv7). These new modules pollute the module cache.

Comment: Exactly what happened to me. How I solved my problem was a more complicated way that is make a new project and copy all the files over to new project, but obviously your solution is better.

Comment: This woks for me too!

Answer (score 10):

I have the same problem. I solved this by going to **XCode** -> **Preferences ...** -> **Download**

[image]

I have iOS **6.1** and **7.0** simulators.

In the project go to **Build Settings** -> **Deployment** and then in  **iOS Deployment Target** section make sure the right iOS simulator version is selected. In my case I chose **iOS 7.0**

[image]

Comment: this page is the closest search i could find for my error "could not build module 'parse'" and channa ly solution worked.  i plugged in my iphone (instead of testing on simulator) and the error auto went away.  (thank you channa ly)

Answer (score 7):

Go to your `DerivedData` directory and remove `ModuleCache` directory.

In terminal:

```
cd /Users/<account_name>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
rm -rf ModuleCache/
```

then reinstall pods: `pod install`.

If it doesn't help try removing whole DerivedData directory and reinstall pods.

Comment: Did not need to reinstall Pods.

Answer (score 5):

After trying all of the above to no avail, I finally reinstalled XCode which did the trick.

Answer (score 4):

So, I also encountered this problem, and discovered the problem was that my Podfile's minimum iOS version was 6.1 while my project's minimum iOS Version was 6.0. Getting these two values aligned resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

My Problem was the app was running in Release mode Changing back to debug...Boom!! starts working

Answer (score 1):

After trying everything else, restarting my computer fixed this.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was Could not build module Twitter Kit. In link Binary with libraries some framework reference were showing as red. Deleting and re adding them worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue and fixed it by deleting Xcode from Applications and reinstalling it again.Worked like charm.

Answer (score 1):

I think I had both a copy of iphone-private-frameworks which collided with the standard headers, so changing the order in the build settings seems to be OK now.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Xcode 8  having similar issue and I tried Xcode reset,deleting derived data none worked finally  resolved the issue by deleting and reinstalling Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

Issue looks like it has to do with deployment - going through both the project, pod project, and individual pods to make sure all were set **the same** was the issue. a bit of a necro, but this is the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

change xcodebuild commnad parameter

```
-sdk iphoneos
```

to

```
-sdk iphonesimulator
```

Answer (score -1):

I was working on xcode 8 beta and project was building on simulator.
But when I tried to run on Device.
I got the same error

**Could not build module 'UIKit"**

It is due to UIKit framwork some how get deleted or Typed something inside it.
Deleting Xcode and reinstalling it.
Error got solved.

Comment: Just a tip: This occurred when I accidentally typed something in `UICollectionView.h`, replacing the particular file physically inside sdk folder with another fresh copy of this header from my friend's sdk solved this. You could also replace the entire sdk folder. This will save you from re-installing.