# Could not build module 'Cocoa' in OS X

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

When I am running my app made for OS X everything works as it should. But when I am trying to archive it I got an error Could not build module 'Cocoa' in the line `#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>`
. What could be a possible problem here?

I've checked and Cocoa.framework is included in my application. I also created a new project and tried to archive it and I have the same issue.

Comment: Have you tried the steps from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22349557/could-not-build-module-uikit-in-cocoapods-since-xcode-5-1 ?

Comment: Yes, I've seen this post but my application is not for iOS it's for OS X.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Short answer

Try reinstalling Xcode. The version of `Cocoa.framework` you're compiling against is screwed up somehow. This will give you a pristine copy, since the version you compile against is inside the Xcode app bundle.

## Long answer

For me, anyways, I managed to mangle the contents of `NSTableCellView.h`.

This was giving me errors like this:

```
<unknown>:0: error: /Applications/Xcode6-Beta5.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Headers/NSTableCellView.h:21: prefix attribute must be followed by an interface or protocol
<unknown>:0: error: /Applications/Xcode6-Beta5.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Headers/NSTableCellView.h:29: extraneous closing brace ('}')
<unknown>:0: error: /Applications/Xcode6-Beta5.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Headers/NSTableCellView.h:33: unexpected '@' in program
<unknown>:0: error: /Applications/Xcode6-Beta5.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Headers/NSTableCellView.h:37: unexpected '@' in program
<unknown>:0: error: /Applications/Xcode6-Beta5.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Headers/NSTableCellView.h:38: unexpected '@' in program
<unknown>:0: error: /Applications/Xcode6-Beta5.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Headers/NSTableCellView.h:42: unexpected '@' in program
<unknown>:0: error: /Applications/Xcode6-Beta5.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Headers/NSTableCellView.h:46: unexpected '@' in program
<unknown>:0: error: /Applications/Xcode6-Beta5.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Headers/NSTableCellView.h:50: unexpected '@' in program
<unknown>:0: error: /Applications/Xcode6-Beta5.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Headers/NSTableCellView.h:52: '@end' must appear in an Objective-C context
<unknown>:0: error: /Applications/Xcode6-Beta5.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Cocoa.framework/Headers/Cocoa.h:13: could not build module 'AppKit'
<unknown>:0: error: could not build Objective-C module 'Cocoa'
<unknown>:0: error: could not build Objective-C module 'Cocoa'
<unknown>:0: error: could not build Objective-C module 'Cocoa'
<unknown>:0: error: could not build Objective-C module 'Cocoa'
<unknown>:0: error: could not build Objective-C module 'Cocoa'
<unknown>:0: error: could not build Objective-C module 'Cocoa'
<unknown>:0: error: could not build Objective-C module 'Cocoa'
<unknown>:0: error: could not build Objective-C module 'Cocoa'
```

The actual error messages led me to the line in question, where I had overwritten an entire `@interface` declaration with just the letter `x`. I just fixed that error, and it compiled again.

If you're not sure what exactly you need to fix, just reinstall Xcode.

Answer (score 3):

Deactivate the "Enables modules (C and objective C) in build settings.

Comment: Deactivating and reactivating, the error went away with a fresh build

Comment: This saved my bacon after wasting hours on this fragile Xcode shyte and nearly punting it into low orbit. Kudos!

Answer (score 0):

You say that you've checked and Cocoa.framework is included in your application, but just make sure that Cocoa.framework is included in "Link Binary With Libraries" section under Build Phases.