# Xcode "Could Not Build Module MobileCoreServices.h" when importing the framework

Tags: objective-c, xcode, import

I'm trying to use `UIImagePickerController`, but I need to include the `MobileCoreServices` framework in order to do so.

I've placed the import statement in my **ViewController.h** file:

```
#import <MobileCoreServices/MobileCoreServices.h>
```

But I get an error:

```
"Could not build module MobileCoreServices.h".
```

I've also already linked the `MobileCoreServices` framework in the project build phrases, and I see it there on the sidebar in the frameworks folder, but it's still giving me an error.

Does anyone know a solution this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Nevermind everyone!

This problem was solved by another SO user on another thread:

[Could not build module 'UIKit" in cocoapods since Xcode 5.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22349557/could-not-build-module-uikit-in-cocoapods-since-xcode-5-1)

Go to your DerivedData directory and remove ModuleCache directory.

In terminal:

```
cd ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
rm -rf ModuleCache/
```

Keeping this thread alive in case anyone else runs into this problem in the future.

Thanks!